# I have setup the codemagic.yaml and Patrol package for testing the integration test cases but I am facing one issue

Tags: android, flutter, codemagic, flutter-patrol

here is my .yaml file for CI/CD . I used the patrol package for write test cases. https://patrol.leancode.co/getting-started/getting-started

```
workflows:
 android_dev_workflow:
    name: workflow for integration testing
    instance_type: mac_mini_m1
    environment:
       groups: 
        - google_credentials 
       flutter: 3.7.3
       xcode: 14.2
       cocoapods: default
       vars: 
         FIREBASE_DEV_PROJECT: "hlp-dev"
    scripts: 
      - name: get flutter packages
        script: |
            flutter pub get
            flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
            dart pub global activate patrol_cli
      - name: create debug and test apk
        script: |
            patrol build android  --target integration_test/hlp_test/hlp_test.dart --flavor dev
      - name: Run Firebase Test Lab Tests
        script: |
            set -ex
            echo $GCLOUD_DEV_KEY_FILE | base64 --decode > ./gcloud_dev_key_file.json
            gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=gcloud_dev_key_file.json
            gcloud --quite config set project $FIREBASE_DEV_PROJECT
            gcloud firebase test android run \
              --type instrumentation \
              --app build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
              --test build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
    artifacts:
       - build/**/outputs/**/*.apk
       - build/**/outputs/**/*.aab
       - build/**/outputs/**/mapping.txt
       - flutter_drive.log        
    publishing:
      email:
        recipients:
           - yogesh@pietechsolution.com
```

I am facing the error on this line
**patrol build android  --target integration_test/hlp_test/hlp_test.dart --flavor dev.**

Here is my output logs

Verbose mode enabled. More logs will be printed.

Received test target: /Users/builder/clone/integration_test/hlp_test/hlp_test.dart

Received Android flavor: dev

Received 5 --dart-define(s) (0 custom, 5 internal)

Received internal --dart-define: PATROL_WAIT=0

Received internal --dart-define: PATROL_APP_PACKAGE_NAME=com.hlp.user.dev

Received internal --dart-define: PATROL_ANDROID_APP_NAME=HLP Dev

Received internal --dart-define: PATROL_TEST_LABEL=hlp_test.dart

Received internal --dart-define: INTEGRATION_TEST_SHOULD_REPORT_RESULTS_TO_NATIVE=false

• Building apk with entrypoint hlp_test.dart...

$ ./gradlew :app:assembleDevDebug -Ptarget=/Users/builder/clone/integration_test/hlp_test/hlp_test.dart -Pdart-defines=UEFUUk9MX1dBSVQ9MA==,UEFUUk9MX0FQUF9QQUNLQUdFX05BTUU9Y29tLmhscC51c2VyLmRldg==,UEFUUk9MX0FORFJPSURfQVBQX05BTUU9SExQIERldg==,UEFUUk9MX1RFU1RfTEFCRUw9aGxwX3Rlc3QuZGFydA==,SU5URUdSQVRJT05fVEVTVF9TSE9VTERfUkVQT1JUX1JFU1VMVFNfVE9fTkFUSVZFPWZhbHNl

**/bin/sh: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
✗ Failed to build apk with entrypoint hlp_test.dart (Gradle build failed with code 127) (9ms)**

Exception: Gradle build failed with code 127

#0 AndroidTestBackend.build. (package:patrol_cli/src/android/android_test_backend.dart:67:9)

#1 DisposeScope.run (package:dispose_scope/src/dispose_scope.dart:44:7)

#2 AndroidTestBackend.build (package:patrol_cli/src/android/android_test_backend.dart:42:5)

#3 BuildAndroidCommand.run (package:patrol_cli/src/commands/build_android.dart:117:7)

#4 CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)

#5 PatrolCommandRunner.runCommand (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:311:18)

#6 PatrolCommandRunner.run (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:255:18)

#7 patrolCommandRunner (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:65:20)

#8 main (file:///Users/builder/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/patrol_cli-1.1.11/bin/main.dart:6:20)

See the logs above to learn what happened. Also consider running with --verbose. If the logs still aren't useful, then it's a bug - please report it.

Exception: Gradle build failed with code 127

#0 AndroidTestBackend.build. (package:patrol_cli/src/android/android_test_backend.dart:67:9)

#1 DisposeScope.run (package:dispose_scope/src/dispose_scope.dart:44:7)

#2 AndroidTestBackend.build (package:patrol_cli/src/android/android_test_backend.dart:42:5)

#3 BuildAndroidCommand.run (package:patrol_cli/src/commands/build_android.dart:117:7)

#4 CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)

#5 PatrolCommandRunner.runCommand (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:311:18)

#6 PatrolCommandRunner.run (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:255:18)

#7 patrolCommandRunner (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:65:20)

#8 main (file:///Users/builder/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/patrol_cli-1.1.11/bin/main.dart:6:20)

Build failed :|

Step 4 script `create debug and test apk` exited with status code 1

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to generate `gradlew`. You can just try building your flutter app first (it'll generate this file), e.g. by `flutter build apk || true`.